# What is the best way to write the date in mm-mm-yyyy in SQL

Tags: sql, database, date, select

I'd like to return a date from SQL in the following format 2011-12-DEC, 2012-01-JAN, 2012-02-FEB, 2012-03-MAR etc...

Currently I have the below code, but don't think it's the best. It also does not return a 0 in front of the month (i.e. 8 rather than 08)

```
print CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE())) + '-'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server, something like this

```
 select convert(varchar(8), getdate(),120)
      + convert(varchar(3),datename(month,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle use TO_CHAR and date formatting.  For Example

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-DD-MON') FROM DUAL
```

There is a wide range of possible date format strings
See [here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-fmt.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you really do want yyyy-mm-mmm then you could get it like so (for SQL server):

```
select  substring(convert(nvarchar, getdate(), 120), 1, 7) 
        + '-' + 
        substring(upper(datename(mm, getdate())), 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `DATE_FORMAT` function or the like, depending on your RDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
you should use a formatter (eg AS [DD/MM/YYYY] ).
All of them are listed here including your requirement for "month" naming
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 113), 4, 8) AS [Mon-YYYY]
```

would give you Apr-2006

just turn it around as you like.